# How to make full CKEditor re-initialization?

Tags: ckeditor

Please help me - I need to make full re-initialization of CKeditor. I don't want to make re-initialization of instances of CKeditor, but I want fully reload it. Is there any way to implement it?
I tried to made next:

```
delete window.CKEDITOR;
```

and then:

```
    //clear for old sources
    $('script[src*="/includes/contentEditor/ckeditor/"]').each(function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });
    $('link[href*="/includes/contentEditor/ckeditor/"]').each(function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });

    //load CKeditor again
    contentEditor.loadjscssfile('/includes/contentEditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js', 'js');
    contentEditor.loadjscssfile('/includes/contentEditor/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js', 'js');
```

My method loads editor but some plugins does not work after reloading. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

I have plugins and I don't need to fully reinitialize CKEditor either, just instances, are you doing it properly?

To remove my instance (my textarea is referenced by ID txt_postMsg):

```
$('#btn_cancelPost').click(function(){
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances.txt_postMsg);
    $('#txt_postMsg').remove();
    $('#cke_txt_postMsg').remove();
});
```

Then I re-create the textarea, and after a 50ms timeout I call the constructor with the textarea again, plugins reload fine. We have some pretty complex plugins for flash/image editing so maybe there's an issue with your plugin?

Answer (score 3):

My version:

```
$$("textarea._cke").each(function(Z) { 
    if (typeof(CKEDITOR.instances[Z.id]) == 'undefined') { 
        CKEDITOR.replace(Z.id, { customConfig : "yourconfig.js"});
    } else {
        CKEDITOR.instances[Z.id].destroy(true);
        CKEDITOR.replace(Z.id, { customConfig : "yourconfig.js"});
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName]);        
CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

**AlfonsoML**
I use CKeditor for dynamically edit different part of site. When I click on some area  of the site it shows popup with CKeditor with content of this area above this area. When I save it I destroy instance of this editor, but if while editing I use link plugin CKeditor can't show editor without page refreshing. Chrome says - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined, Mozilla - x.config.skin is undefined(I try to set config.skin and it show another error - z is undefined).

I hope the full re-init can help.

P.S. Sorry I can find how to answer on your comment...

Comment: The ajax.html and div_replace.html samples show how it's possible to create and destroy CKEditor instances without any need for "full reinitialization", so you should check how you are using CKEditor to fix that bug instead of adding a strange workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a way to re-initialize the editor and the only solution that I end up is to delete the instance and create a new ID.

Here's my code.

```
var editor = 'myeditor'
var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[editor];

if(typeof instance != 'undefined')
{
    instance.destroy();
    $(".cke_editor_" + editor).remove();

    //make a new id
    editor = (Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10););
}

CKEDITOR.replace(editor, 
{
}
```

It's not perfect but it works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[your_ckeditor_id];
editor.mode = 'source';
editor.setMode('wysiwyg');
```

OR

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[your_ckeditor_id];
editor.setData(editor.getData());
```